# Scheme list manipulation

Tags: recursion, scheme

I cant figure out this scheme code please help. Compute-frequencies takes in two separate lists looking-for-list and pool-list. It is supposed to return a list that shows how many times everything in looking-for-list is in pool-list.
I know I am close it is just some little error most likely having to do with the recursive call after making it through pool-list.

```
(define (compute-frequencies looking-for-list pool-list) 
  (define (helper looking-for-list pool-list current-frequency frequency-list)  ; keeps track of finished list and iterates through both lists
    (if (null? looking-for-list) (reverse frequency-list)                       ; finding the number of times data in looking-for-list are in pool-list
    (if (null? pool-list)
        (helper (cdr looking-for-list) pool-list 0 (cons current-frequency frequency-list))
        (if (equal? (car looking-for-list) (car pool-list))
        (helper looking-for-list (cdr pool-list) (+ 1 current-frequency) frequency-list)
        (helper looking-for-list (cdr pool-list) current-frequency frequency-list)))))

 (helper looking-for-list pool-list 0 '() ))
```

Comment: IMHO, this is *much* easier if you break it down into subproblems; first define a function that computes the frequency of *one* item in a list, and then use that in `compute-frequencies`. Then you only need to worry about recursing down one list in each function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright reading your code it seems like your algorithm itself is perfectly fine. The problem is much simpler.

Look at your code, once you've checked all the elements of `pool-list` for the first element in your `looking-for-list` you want to restore `pool-list` to its original state. To do this, you call `helper` with `pool-list` as `pool-list`. You almost certainly mean the one defined in the `compute-frequency` arguments but Scheme takes the one in `helper`'s arguments since it shadow's the one in `compute-frequency`. This means that after the first iteration, `pool-list` is just `'()` so the frequency of everything else is 0.

To solve this, do some renaming. In the future, try to remember that Scheme variables can and will shadow ones in a larger scope. And also, try using `cond` instead of nested if statements. Much more readable in Scheme (it's how I found this problem)

Comment: Don't forget to click the check mark, so @jozefg gets credit for the answer!